# Where is main function?

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In Metro app created by VS11, where can I find main function?
I know it sounds silly but I've tried to look for it and couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply...there is not! :)
The main entry point is App::App(), take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699878(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: they do mention main in the link you've provided

Comment: Yes but only for console applications!

Answer (score 3):

There's not one in your code. Instead, it's in the Metro framework somewhere, and it'll wind up calling your App::App() method.